# 목표를 이루려면 /달성하고자, why is 달성하고자 wrong?

Tags: grammar, meaning

2 is correct but can anyone explain why 3 is wrong in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The most important restriction regarding the use of -고자 is that you need to use the **same animate subject** before and after it (Note: This animate subject includes an individual, a group of people or animals, an institution, a country, etc.). I cannot tell you why, but this is how people use it.

The preceding part of that sentence has "you" (or "I" or "we") as the subject, whereas the following has "철저한 계획과 꾸준한 노력" as the subject. Therefore, the sentence has the *two subjects* and the following has an *inanimate* one.

If you wish to use 달성하고자, you have to rewrite the following. For example, it is correct to say "목표를 달성하고자 한다면 철저한 계획과 꾸준한 노력을 해야 한다." because it has **one animate subject**, "you" (or "I" or "we"), but it is better to say "목표를 달성하고자 한다면 계획을 철저히 하고/세우고 노력을 꾸준히 해야 한다."

Comment: Actually the last sentence still sounds a bit strange. There are few points. 1. '철저한 계획' should be used with '세워야 한다' rather than '해야 한다'. 2. '달성하고자' is better to be with '했다' or to be modified as '달성하고자 한다면'. Their tenses are different IMO.

Comment: @JunyoungClareJang I have just edited my answer. Just one point I would add is that we can use 계획을 해야 한다 as, using 을, we can separate 계획 and 하다 from the verb 계획하다. Still, 계획을 짜다 and 계획을 세우다 are collocations that will sound better.

Comment: Yes, I agree that my 'should be' was maybe too strong. Though I think in the context of '철저한 계획과 꾸준한 노력을 해야 한다', the combination of '철저한 계획' and '해야 한다' feels awkward. Maybe because that '해야 한다' is used to represent two different verbs. ('세우다' for '계획', and '쏟다'/'투자하다' for '노력')

Comment: It depends on the perspective. 하다 can be regarded not only as a pro-verb but also as a verbalizer (although I am not sure whether it is the correct term) here. Even though you feel that way, 고려대학교 한국어대사전 has this example: "테러리스트는 치밀한 계획과 준비를 한 후 테러할 목표점을 결정한다." Therefore, ○○(action 1)와/과 ○○(action 2)을/를 하다 is a natural usage pattern.

Comment: Actually, that example seems natural. Then probably there is other reason... Though I don't know it.

Comment: I ponder it bit more, and I think it's (again) because of timing. '계획' precedes '노력' in this context (since '노력' will be poured during the process, where '계획' is planned ahead), whereas '계획' and '준비' are done in (approximately) the same stage. Again, it's just my opinion and nothing official or so.

Comment: OK, then I will just list other examples found via some Googling: "여러분은 어떤 독(讀)한 계획과 실천을 하고 계신가요?" "...어떤 선택을 하든 계획과 실천을 하기 위해서는..." "과거를 성찰하고 혁신적 변화를 담은 계획과 실천을 해야" "이를 확보하기 위한 사전 계획과 노력을 하는 것이..." "자신의 진로를 위한 기본적인 계획과 노력을 하고 있습니다."

Comment: Thankfully, all of those examples sound (somewhat consistently) little weird for me from a picky point of view. Anyway, I haven't meant those are completely wrong and should be changed to match with my (somewhat picky) palate. I just want to present some opinion on your last example which looks very little strange for me, and it's even updated now, so I won't bother you more. Thank you for all your research and googling.